# GAS Spreadsheet avoid getting duplicates by marking as "SENT", not working?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this script in Google Spreadsheet and it fetches all the rows marked "READY" just fine, then it sets the value in column "W"(23) to "SENT", and then I am trying to avoid fetching duplicates, by marking the column as "SENT" but then when I run the code again, it ignores the "SENT" that it just pasted? What is wrong here?

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("12y85GmJ94s6k3213j2nGK8rFr0GOfd_Emfk8WHu_MUQ");
var stitchSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet8");
var orderSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

var SENT = "SENT";

function getOrders() {

    var range  = orderSheet.getDataRange();
    var orders  = range.getValues();  

    for (var i = 1; i < orders.length; i++) {
        var row = orders[i];
        var status = row[1];
        var order = row[4]; 
        var name = row[5]; 
        var system = row[22]; 

        if(system != SENT){ 
            if(status.toString() === 'READY'){
                orderSheet.getRange(i,23).setValue(SENT);
                stitchSheet.appendRow([order,name]); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use troubleshooting techniques.  Put a `Logger.log('system: ' + system);` statement right after the `var system = row[22];` statement.  What is printed to the Logs?  Enter a `Logger.log(system != SENT);` statement, and check the Logs.  Also, try using `!==` (double equal sign) instead of single equal sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, so there must be a logical error somewhere. I've noticed that you made `var i` in the for loop `1`. I do not know if this is intentional or not, but the index of arrays pretty much always starts with 0 in most programming languages, which means that you'll start at row 2 of your sheet, not row 1.

#### Finding logical errors

To find logical errors you need to learn how to use the debugger console in the script editor.

Put breakpoints on the lines I mark with a star below:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("12y85GmJ94s6k3213j2nGK8rFr0GOfd_Emfk8WHu_MUQ");
var stitchSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet8");
var orderSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

var SENT = "SENT";

function getOrders() {

    var range  = orderSheet.getDataRange();
*   var orders  = range.getValues();  

    for (var i = 1; i < orders.length; i++) {
*       var row = orders[i];
        var status = row[1];
        var order = row[4]; 
        var name = row[5]; 
*       var system = row[22]; 

        if(system != SENT){ 
            if(status.toString() === 'READY'){
                orderSheet.getRange(i,23).setValue(SENT);
                stitchSheet.appendRow([order,name]); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Start the debugger and it will stop at the first breakpoint. Inspect what value `range` has. Expanding `This` should let you find `orderSheet` and `SENT` (since they are outside the function and should be in the scope). If not you've got a problem here.

Go to the next breakpoint and inspect `orders`, it should have an array of arrays now. You can inspect that you've got the right values, if not, skip forward to the next breakpoint and look at what `row` is.